# Amazon S3: Accessing files after setting bucket restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've set a bucket policy on an Amazon S3 bucket so that the files can only be requested from the domain where my website is hosted. (Denying access if the URL does not match that of my domain).

However, now I can't access my own files from within the file explorer in the AWS console, which is really impractical.

Is there a rule I can add to make my files accessible from the AWS console without having to temporarily remove the bucket policy every time I want to view/download some of my files?

Comment: Have you tried adding another `allow` to only your AWS account?

Comment: You can also use a S3 browser with your credentials such as CloudBerry (windows) or DragonDisk (Linux/Mac)